# Sending the exception message to the client if a web api action method errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

I have a try catch in my controller action method and if there is an error I would like to send the exception.message to the client using the proper method that implements IActionResult. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I have tried searching through the entire list of built in HTTP Methods for Web API Core 1.0 and can't figure out how to properly return an exception message to the client when there is a 500 server error. I can;t find anything on google so I am assuming people don't do this...

Comment: You will need to build something yourself, unfortunately. Check this out: http://jameschambers.com/2014/06/day-14-bootstrap-alerts-and-mvc-framework-tempdata/

Comment: @DunningKrugerEffect you mean to tell me there is no way to send an error message back?

Comment: You would return an error message like you would any other piece of information from a Controller to a View. You just need to build the delivery method. There is nothing built in that will handle a thrown exception and display a friendly message to a user.

Answer (score 0):

You really only want to be catching exceptions in your try/catch that you can handle gracefully in the code. If a internal server error does occur, a 500 would be the appropriate response.

You should be validating the requests in order to prevent the 500 and when validation fails, then you can return the appropriate status code.

A very generic example might look like this in Web Api 2:

```
        if (validationFailed)
        {
            return BadRequest("Your request failed because xyz..");
        }
```

Comment: Lets say in my business logic I purposely throw an exception in the code if there is a setup error. I then have this exception in my action method because the catch part of the try catch catches it. How do I give the client an idea of what the exception error message is about? Is this not a common thing people want to be able to do?

Comment: @BlakeRivell I just updated my answer with an example that'll work in Web Api 2

Comment: You may want to reconsider throwing an exception instead of some other action. Here's a great read about Exceptions from Eric Lippert. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @Elliott thank you, but can't find the message in the repsonse on the client.